# undefined method `key' for nil:NilClass in UsersController #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-variables, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-6

I've followed Ryan Bates [Railscast for multi-step forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?autoplay=true) and I've followed the suggestion of AStockwell's answer for uploading user avatar files via carrierwave on the [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355152/multi-step-form-with-image-uploader/64911044#64911044).

The strange thing is that when I submit the form the user sign up info gets inserted into my db (I can confirm this by searching in my user list via active admin resource), but I'm still receiving the error:

> undefined method `key' for nil:NilClass in my UsersController

I receive this error right around the line in my controller

> @user.save

And when I call @user or @user.avatar, @user.name, etc. it succesfully returns back all the right info.

I'm confused about this error, as it seems vague to me, does anyone have any clue about how I can approach to solve this?

Here is my UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  layout "success"

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end


  def new
    session[:user_params] ||= {}
    @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
    @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
  end


  def create


    # If the submission POST contains an image, set it as an instance variable,
    # because we're going to remove it from the params
    if params[:user] && params[:user][:avatar] && !params[:user][:avatar].is_a?(String)
      # Store the UploadedFile object as an instance variable
      @image = params[:user][:avatar]
      # Remove the uploaded object from the submission POST params, since we
      # don't want to merge the whole object into the user's session
      params[:user].delete(:avatar)
    end

  # Merge existing session with POST params
  session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user].to_unsafe_h) if params[:user]



    # Instantiate model from newly merged session/params
   @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
       # Increment the current step in the session form
   @user.current_step = session[:user_step]


   # After deep_merge, bring back the image
 if @image
   # This adds the image back to the Carrierwave mounted uploader (which
   # re-runs any processing/versions specified in the uploader class):
   @user.avatar = @image
   # The mounted uploader now has the image stored in the Carrierwave cache,
   # and provides us with the cache identifier, which is what we will save
   # in our session:
   session[:user_params][:avatar] = @user.avatar_cache
   session[:thumbnail_cached] = @user.avatar.url(:thumbnail)
 end



      if params[:back_button]
        @user.previous_step
      elsif @user.last_step?
        # Re-populate the Carrierwave uploader's cache with the cache identifier
        # saved in the session
        @user.avatar_cache = session[:user_params][:avatar]
       # Save the model
        @user.save
      else
        @user.next_step
      end


      session[:user_step] = @user.current_step


      if @user.new_record?
      render "new"

      else

    # remove the onboarding session
    session[:user_step] = session[:user_params] = nil

    # keep hold of that user and begin a new session with their newly created account
    session[:user_id] = @user.id

    # let the user know they've signed up
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to TimeSink!"

    # go back to previous page the user was on
   redirect_to cookies[:original_referrer]


    NewMemberMailer.greeting(@user).deliver_now
    NewMemberMailer.newmember(@user).deliver_now
    end
end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted"
    redirect_to root_path
  end



  def form_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user, :name, :location, :username, :avatar, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :submissions)
  end
end
```

And here is my UserModel:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord


  attr_writer :current_step


  acts_as_voter

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarImageUploader

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :submissions

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, :on => :create }
  validates :password, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 8, :message => "Must be at least 8 characters"}, :on => :create

  has_secure_password

  def to_param
    username
  end

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[name username location avatar email_password]
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
  end

  def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end

  def all_valid?
    steps.all? do |step|
      self.current_step = step
      valid?
    end
  end

  def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.forgot_password(self).deliver# This sends an e-mail with a link for the user to reset the password
end
# This generates a random password reset token for the user
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

end
```

And here is the full stack trace error:

```
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:453:in `copy_to'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:340:in `store'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:86:in `store!'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:66:in `block in store!'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:15:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:65:in `store!'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:105:in `each'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:105:in `store!'
carrierwave (2.1.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:401:in `store_avatar!'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:263:in `block in conditional'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `block in invoke_after'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `each'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `invoke_after'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:825:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:339:in `committed!'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:127:in `commit_records'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:265:in `block in commit_transaction'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:255:in `commit_transaction'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:293:in `block in within_new_transaction'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:366:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:314:in `save'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61:in `create'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:195:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.4) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the error, that will help determine where it's coming from

Comment: Hi Max, happily! I just updated to show the stack trace in my original post.

Comment: Following a 10 year old tutorial seems kind of masochistic. Ryan did do a good job back in the day but I doubt it has aged well. Surely you can find something a bit more recent? Or use a gem like wicked?

Comment: I didn't like wicked gem because apparently it calls to save the user to db after the inital step, without the rest of the attributes. This older solution, despite being controller heavy, actually seemed to fit what I was looking for best. The only thing that was giving me trouble is the avatar file upload, but the SO post I referenced seemed to have pointed me in a good direction, as the file is uploading. Just this last undefined method error has me stumped! Where do you think this 'key' comes from?

Comment: All S3 objects have a "key" which is basically the path it's stored at. At some point in your code (or the gem's code), it's trying to call the "key" method on an object which is nil (and probably shouldn't be). I don't know the exact solution but I would recommend double checking the guides for the gem you're using. And yeah, following old tutorials can be a hard time. For example they might be using an older version of the gem that works differently.

Comment: ah! That would make a lot of sense. I believe then it has something to do with the active-record-session-store gem that I'm using. The problem was that the user avatar upload photos are too big for a session to store. And this gem made it possible to get around that. Perhaps there's more I need to configure. Thanks for the direction Max. 

 https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

Comment: If you have time to look at the gem (I'm still a beginner and learning a lot) do you think its related to setting up the initializer with the 'key' here:


Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_my_app_session'

https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

Comment: @AaronZ I don't actually think it's related to activerecord-session_store. The error points to carrierwave which is what made me think the "key" in question here was for S3. There are multiple types of "keys" in an application - I see how that could be confusing ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error.

I had to include attr_writer :avatar_cache in my User model.